# For a convex function, will the $-\nabla f$ always point towards the minima?

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Assume that we are given some $f$, which we know is a convex function. We are now trying to find the minima of this function so we take the $-\nabla f$ to find the direction of steepest decline.

My question is, is this guaranteed to point towards the minima. For simple functions like a paranoid I am imagining yes, but this seems way too good to be true.

Comment: "For simple functions like a paranoid" -- I'm afraid what that looks like ...

Comment: $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4$ is clearly convex but $-\nabla f$ does not always point towards the origin.

Comment: What do you mean by "point towards the minima"? Usually $-\nabla f(x)$ does not point directly towards the global minimizer. That would be too good to be true (because then after a single gradient evaluation the optimization problem could be solved just by searching along a single direction).

Comment: @littleO: indeed. *To solve a convex minimization problem, you only need to evaluate $\nabla f$ at two distinct points.* Too good to be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in the sense that the inner product will be nonnegative (though it will of course not always point in the *exact* direction of the minimizer). If $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function, $x^*$ is a minimizer, and $x$ is any other point in the domain in which a subgradient $f'(x)$ exists, then we have by definition of subgradient: 
$$ f(y) \geq f(x) + f'(x)^T(y-x) \quad \forall y \in \mathcal{X} $$
and evaluating at $y=x^*$ gives
$$ f(x^*) \geq f(x) + f'(x)^T(x^*-x)\geq f(x^*)+f'(x)^T(x^*-x)$$
where the final inequality uses $f(x)\geq f(x^*)$ by definition of minimizer. So we get:
$$ \boxed{(-f'(x))^T(x^*-x) \geq 0}$$

---

An example is $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y) = ax^2 + by^2$ for $a>0, b>0$.  Then $(x^*,y^*)=(0,0)$ is the unique minimizer and at any nonzero vector $(x,y)$ we have: 
$$ -f'(x,y) = [-2ax; -2by] $$
The direction from $(x,y)$ to $(0,0)$ is $(-x,-y)$, and indeed $(-2ax; -2by)$ has a nonnegative inner product with $(-x,-y)$, even though it does not point in exactly the same direction when $a\neq b$.